# Select case statement not working in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view, case-when

I have `Kpi_definition` table in which for particular event_id there can be more than one `KPI_DEF_ID` present. For example for event_id = `10250` there are two `KPI_DEF_ID`. I have to check first for the event_id the `KPI_DEF_ID` is present or not and if it is not present then set the `STATUS` to `'N'`. In another condition i have to check if `KPI_DEF_ID` is present and none of the field value of `KPI_ACTIVE_INITIAL,KPI_ACTIVE_CURRENT,KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL,KPI_ACTIVE_DOWNTIME = 'N'` for all `KPI_DEF_ID` then `OS.STATUS` else `'N'`.

[image]

I have written the below select query but its not working. I am writing this query inside view.

```
SELECT 'EVENT'     AS OBJECT_TYPE, 
       os.event_id AS OBJECT_ID, 
       CASE 
         WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT KD.kpi_def_id 
                         FROM   rator_monitoring_configuration.kpi_definition KD 
                         WHERE  KD.event_id = os.event_id 
                                AND KD.kpi_type IN ( 19, 21 )) THEN 'N' 
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT KD.kpi_def_id 
                     FROM   rator_monitoring_configuration.kpi_definition KD 
                     WHERE  KD.event_id = os.event_id 
                            AND KD.kpi_type IN ( 19, 21 ) 
                            AND ( KD.kpi_active_initial = 'N' 
                                   OR KD.kpi_active_current = 'N' 
                                   OR KD.kpi_active_manual = 'N' 
                                   OR KD.kpi_active_downtime = 'N' )) THEN 'N' 
         ELSE os.status 
       END         AS OBJECT_STATUS 
FROM RATOR_MONITORING.EVENT_STATUS OS
```

Comment: Not working as in you get an error or not working as in the result is not what you want?

Comment: You need to create two different case statements and not one. This comment is made for your "In another condition "

Comment: I am not getting any error, i am not getting the result what i want. @realspirituals can you please tell me how can i do that ? I am not sure without loop its possible ?

Comment: Where is you `FROM` ? Did you truncate your query in copy/paste or did you forget it in your query ?

Comment: i have edited my query .

Comment: @Rahul , show us your actual result and the result you wanted to have, please :-) or provide us a SQLFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select decode(kpi_def_id,NULL,'N',
       case when instr(ini||curr||downtime||manual,'N',1) = 0 
       then status else 'N' end)
from ex_6
```

hi rahul,

this query worked on my machine .Fullfilled your requirement.Please mark up the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try using another `CASE` in the `ELSE` part..
Write query like:

```
SELECT 'EVENT'     AS OBJECT_TYPE, 
       os.event_id AS OBJECT_ID, 
       CASE 
         WHEN NOT EXISTS(SELECT KD.kpi_def_id 
                         FROM   rator_monitoring_configuration.kpi_definition KD 
                         WHERE  KD.event_id = os.event_id 
                                AND KD.kpi_type IN ( 19, 21 )) THEN 'N' 
         ELSE CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT KD.kpi_def_id 
                     FROM   rator_monitoring_configuration.kpi_definition KD 
                     WHERE  KD.event_id = os.event_id 
                            AND KD.kpi_type IN ( 19, 21 ) 
                            AND ( KD.kpi_active_initial = 'N' 
                                   OR KD.kpi_active_current = 'N' 
                                   OR KD.kpi_active_manual = 'N' 
                                   OR KD.kpi_active_downtime = 'N' )) THEN 'N' 
             ELSE os.status 
             END  
       END         AS OBJECT_STATUS 
FROM RATOR_MONITORING.EVENT_STATUS OS
```

Comment: False. you can use many `when` in a `case`, it's the meaning of a `CASE`

Comment: its not working. The logic is not correct. I want to say is if for example for KPI_DEF_ID=1000356 if any of the field is N and for KPI_DEF_ID = 1000389 any of the field is N then set the status to 'N' . The other condition is for particular event_id and kpi_def_id,if all the filed is 'N' then set it to 'N'. So we need more case i guess. The case condition is not correct.  Here its checking only first condition for KPI_DEF_ID = 1000356 and return the result to N which is not correct.

Comment: If i am understanding you perfectly then just check `if KPI_DEF_ID is present and none of the field value of KPI_ACTIVE_INITIAL = 'N' and  KPI_ACTIVE_CURRENT = 'N' and KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL = 'N' and KPI_ACTIVE_DOWNTIME = 'N' ` then `os.status ` ELSE `'N'` because all other condition would be fulfilled in else part..

Answer (score 1):

```
select case when decode(kpi_def_id,NULL,'N',col,0,'N') <> 'N' then status else 'N' end case from
(
 select kpi_def_id,instr(ini||curr||downtime||manual,'Y',1) col,ex_6.status status from ex_6
)
```

This query works i have concatenated initial,downtime,current,manual column and with use of instr function finding whether it has character 'Y' in that string and using the result returned by inner query in outer query and with help of decode function we can achieve the expected result

Regards,

Comment: its not working. The logic is not correct. I want to say is if for example for KPI_DEF_ID=1000356 if any of the field is N and for KPI_DEF_ID = 1000389 any of the field is N then set the status to 'N' . The other condition is for particular event_id and kpi_def_id,if all the filed is 'N' then set it to 'N'. So we need more case i guess. The case condition is not correct.  Here its checking only first condition for KPI_DEF_ID = 1000356 and return the result to N which is not correct.

Comment: i have not used table name and column name as urs but this is giving desired result .i have tried executed it on my machine then posted the solution